# smartgwt setAttribute command does not work

Tags: gwt, css, attributes, styles, smartgwt

setAttribute does not work for fontsize in htmlflow or statictextitem title?? has somebody worked it out?i have to set something to enable settin attributes for htmlflow to set color or font through command setAttribute?

Comment: Do you want to apply style? Or let me know which kind of attribute you want to apply to the HTMLFlow or StaticTextItem?

Comment: I have already applied style in constructor, now i want to change it dynamically.Color of the HTMLFLOW?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using redraw() after changing dynamically the color of the htmlflow?